# Calculating unknown Relative Velocity from Given 2 Known Relative Velocities for speeds comparable to speed of Light

Tags: special-relativity, relative-motion

Dear fellow physics lovers,

Given 3 objects ***A***, ***B*** and ***C***, travelling with relative velocities such that

$\vec{v_{AB}}$ = Velocity of Object ***A*** with respect to Object ***B***

$\vec{v_{BC}}$ = Velocity of Object ***B*** with respect to Object ***C***

We know that for **Non Relativistic Speeds** (where ***v<<c***) we can calculate Velocity of Object ***A*** with respect to Object ***C*** $\vec{v_{AC}}$ as follows

$\vec{v_{AC}}= \vec{v_{AB}} + \vec{v_{BC}}$

The above formula is also valid for **Relativistic Speeds** when $\vec{v_{AB}}$ and $\vec{v_{BC}}$ are **Parallel Velocities** (using ***Einstein's Velocity Addition Formula***). However I would like to know is there some formula available for **Relativistic Speeds** for **Non Parallel Velocities** where we can find $\vec{v_{AC}}$ given $\vec{v_{AB}}$ and $\vec{v_{BC}}$ (i.e. when $\vec{v_{AB}}$ and $\vec{v_{BC}}$ are ***Not Parallel***)

Ideally I am looking for a general solution for both parallel and non parallel velocity cases.

Thanks.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity

Comment: what about non parallel velocities?

Comment: The general case is there as well.

Comment: In general cases the velocities Vab + Vbc is not equal to Vac as per my calculations. This is the primary reason I asked the question

Comment: You’re not being clear about your problem. However, please be aware that a check-my-work question would be off-topic for this site. Wikipedia has all the relevant formulas. If you have a *conceptual* question about one of them, then ask.

Comment: @ g-smith: Why don't you do the calculations based on Wikipedia formulas, present them here and prove me wrong? Also I shall appreciate knowing what part of my question is not clear to you

Comment: Requesting all people who have anonymously downvoted this question to kindly provide logical reason(s) for downvoting

Comment: However $\vec{V_{AC}}=\vec{V_{AB}} + \vec{V_{BC}}$ for parallel velocities, not for non parallel ones. That is why my question asks for a general solution for both.

Comment: @pm-2ring: Why don't you provide me a calculation and prove me wrong?

Comment: @pm-2ring: In the first calculation you have used the Einstein's Velocity Addition Formula. In the second calculation you have directly added the 2 Velocities. They are bound to be different. But this is not how you verify $\vec{V_{ac}}  \neq \vec{V_{ab}} + \vec{V_{bc}} $. The correct method of verification is much longer and takes into account  $\vec{V_a}$ , $\vec{V_b}$  and , $\vec{V_c}$ separately, Calculates $\vec{V_{ab}}$, $\vec{V_{bc}}$ and , $\vec{V_{ac}}$  and then verifies whether $\vec{V_{ac}}  \neq \vec{V_{ab}} + \vec{V_{bc}} $ or $\vec{V_{ac}}  = \vec{V_{ab}} + \vec{V_{bc}} $

Comment: @pm-2ring: And all of the above calculations must be done using Einstein's Velocity Addition formula

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed in the comments, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity) they gave a formula for the case where frame B is moving in the positive x-direction with respect to C. At first glance, it might not seem to be a general answer as we are restricted x-direction, but it is quite general since we can always rotate the coordinates of frame C such that the +x direction coincides with the $\vec{V}_{BC}$. There is also a cumbersome formula given there when it is $\vec{V}_{BC}$ is not along the x-direction.

This problem can be understood more thoroughly using [four vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) and [Lorentz transformation tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Tensor_formulation).
Let $X$ ,$X'$ & $X''$ be the [position 4-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-position) of a Spacetime event in frames C, B & A respectively. Then-
$$X''=B(\vec{V_{AB}})X'=B(\vec{V_{AB}})B(\vec{V_{BC}})X $$
In general,
$$ X''\neq B(\vec{V_{AC}})X$$
$$X''=R(\theta)B(\vec{V_{AC}})X$$
Here $B(\vec{u})$ is a lorentx boost along $\vec{u}$.This $R(\theta)$ is called [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation). So by multiplicating these 2 Lorentz boosts and dividing it into rotaion+boost we can find $\vec{V_{AC}}$ form the boost matrix.

**Edit:**
Writing equations using 3-velocity is cumbersome. Using the [four-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) we can very simply write it as
$$u'^\alpha=\Lambda^{\alpha}{}_{\beta}{}u^\beta $$
Where $\Lambda^{\alpha}{}_{\beta}{}$ is the geenral boost given by-
[image: General Boost]. $v^\alpha=\gamma c(1,\beta_x,\beta_y,\beta_z)$ is the four velocity of the frame $K'$ wrt $K$ and $u^\alpha$ ,$u'^\alpha$ are the four velocities of a particle in frames $K$, $K'$ respectively.
This is the big formula without using 4-vectors
[image](from Wiki)

Comment: Hi Kasi, Thanks for the answer. Maybe it works. However I would like to see actual calculation. Please provide me your email id so that I can mail the calculations that I have done. They are significantly long to be shared here. I would like you to append your calculations to that excel file to show the the result. Do you think you would do that?

Comment: Unless I can actually see the calculations, or any formula is given such a way that I can calculate the result just by plugging in the values I will have my doubts.

Comment: @Arup Hore Well, the general cumbersome formula is given in Wikipedia, and also it is written on the answer by Emmy and I also added it now. That formula is correct but better to use four-velocity as it makes the formula compact. The only problem is we cannot relate the 2 frames A and C by a Lorentz boost.

Comment: The cumbersome formula that you are referring to is called the "Einstein Velocity Addition Formula". As I have mentioned in the comment to Emmy, I have done my calculations based on this formula and this formula only works when $\vec{V_{AB}}$ and $\vec{V_{BC}}$  are ***Parallel Velocities***. It does not work when $\vec{V_{AB}}$ and $\vec{V_{BC}}$  are ***Non Parallel Velocities***. I have accordingly updated the question. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @ArupHore It works for nonparallel velocities also. Clearly in the proof, they took components of u'(or V_{AB}) parallel to v(or V_{BC}) and perpendicular v. They haven't restricted to the case where u' is parallel to v.

Comment: You can add any kind of velocities (Parallel and Non Parallel) using this formula. What I am saying is that when 2 Non parallel Velocities $\vec{V_{AB}}$  (velocity of A with Respect to B) and $\vec{V_{BC}} $ (velocity of B with Respect to C) are added it is not the same as $\vec{V_{AC}} $ (velocity of A with Respect to C). I can show you my calculations with actual values if we can connect over phone/Anydesk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115565/discussion-between-kasi-reddy-sreeman-reddy-and-arup-hore).

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are asking is on Wikipedia:

$$\mathbf{v}_{AC} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{(\mathbf{v}_{BC}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{AB})}{c^2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{AB}+\frac{\mathbf{v}_{BC}}{\gamma_{AB}}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\gamma_{AB}}{1+\gamma_{AB}}(\mathbf{v}_{BC}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{AB})\mathbf{v}_{AB}\right)$$

where $\gamma_{AB} = (1-(\mathbf{v_{AB}}/c)^2)^{-1/2}$ as usual.

Note that you recover $\mathbf{v}_{AC} = \mathbf{v}_{AB}+\mathbf{v}_{BC}$ for nonrelativistic speeds

Comment: This is simply the Velocity addition formula. I have done the calculations based on this formula and this does not work for non parallel velocities, that is when Vab and Vbc are not parallel